# 2 node.js servers communicating using nowjs?

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I saw a lot of examples of nowjs that uses a node.js server and a web client but I do not really know how to connect 2 node.js servers using nowjs.

Basically, I have 2 physical machines A and B and I have one node.js server running on each. When I launch the server on machine A I'd like it to open a connection to B and then I'd like to be able to call method on A from B whenever I need to. I understood nowjs is a good library to perform this.

Any idea / clues to set this up ?

***UPDATE***

Seems like DNode is a best candidate for this

Comment: Have you tried hook.io ?

Comment: @raynos, nop, do not know this one. I'll check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've thrown together this node-based client for NowJS (essentially a port of the client-side library, with some minor changes to make it not attempt cross-browser compatibility, since V8 isn't IE6 at all). The documentation is a bit lacking at the moment, so feel free to ask any questions you might have.

https://github.com/Flotype/nowclient